# Random letters instead of numbers in dynamic text AS 2.0

Tags: actionscript-2

So I'm trying to program a game using flash, and it's my very first time and I can't get something to work.
In the game, a ball will float across the screen and if you click on it you get 2 points. Except when I test it, the first time I click on the ball I get the letters 'eoceeeo' and if I click the ball again I get the letters 'eeoS'. The dynamic text is on a layer with the first frame having the AS of

```
var _root.score = 0;
gameScore.text = _root.score;
```

The dynamic text has a varible of _root.score and a name of gameScore
The floating ball has the AS of

```
on(release) { _root.score+=2; _root.gameScore.text = _root.score; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you click on your `gameScore` dynamic text field, you can scroll down to its `Variable` property and set that as `_root.score`. That way, you do not have to call `gameScore.text = _root.score` every time the score changes - it will simply update automatically.

Also, if you remove the `var` from in front of `_root.score = 0`, it will be easier for ActionScript to handle. Perhaps, you are casting the `score` variable as an integer, and the dynamic text field is having trouble displaying it as a string of characters. This can also be solved with `String(_root.score)` and `score.toString()`.

That should make your code a bit less complex, and help for you to identity your random letters problem, which can't be solved specifically with the information you have here. Hope that helps!